# Can CSound or SuperCollider be used to make softsynths?

Tags: sound-design, audio-recording, synthesizer, soundfont

Can I use these two or something else to generate waveform of sound and then use it as soft synth or generate soundfont?

Answer (score 4):

SuperCollider *is* a softsynth. CSound *has* a soft synth as well as a scoring system.

You can also use CSound as a [VST instrument or effect.](http://csounds.com/manual/html/CommandCsoundVST.html) I'm not aware of a VST wrapper for SuperCollider, but SC can respond to both MIDI and OSC data, so it shouldn't be too hard to hook up with your DAW.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use Csound as a VST using Cabbage. 
http://thecabbagefoundation.org/

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly record the output of Csound or SuperCollider (or anything really) and load that up into your sampler of choice. If you specifically want to use the soundfont format, you'll need some kind of soundfont editor.

Answer (score 0):

You could generate sounds in supercollider or CSound if you want. Using them as VST instruments is not exactly straightforward. I think that's easier done with CSound than with Supercollider. I do know that there is an audiounit for supercollider, in case you are on mac.